# Special chars does not convert to html entities (html_entity_decode not working)

Tags: php, html-entities

I'm trying to encode special entities with a function, here what I'm trying to do: 
its a ratable function, with ratables stars, i have two functions that displays a ratable message, one is displaying default results, and the second when i give it a new rate

```
function showStars($ratableKey) {
...
$textDesc = "<div id=\"rabidRating-$ratingId-description\" class=\"ratingText\">"
                .$this->getStarMessage($rating)."</div>"; 
echo $textDesc 
}
```

i am call the getStarMessage in two different ways

```
   function getStarMessage($rating) {
    $stars = $this->percentToStars($rating['rating']);
    if ($rating[totalRatings] > 1) $s = "s";
    $div_stars = "<div class=\"rate\">";

    $result= "$stars/$this->stars ".$div_stars." ($rating[totalRatings] avis)</div>";
    $result=  html_entity_decode($result);
    return $result;
}
```

In the defaut way (in showStars function ) it works fine (with or without the html_entity_decode)
but when I called the getStarMessage function in another function

```
function doVote($ratableId, $percent) {

    ...

    $rating = $this->loadRating($id);
    $return = $this->getStarMessage($rating);

    echo $return; ==> the problem is here

}
```

in source code it displays

```
<div class="ratingText " id="rabidRating-9-description">2.8/5 &lt;div class="rate"&gt; (141 avis)&lt;/div&gt;</div>
```

and therefore, the output is this

```
2.8/5 <div class="rate"> (142 Stars)</div>
```

It's not displaying as html entities but as simple string.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Here some screenshot :

displaying default : 
[image: Displaying default withour rating]

After rating (clik on stars)
[image: After clik on stars to rate]

Answer (score 0):

You want that div.rate to be rendered as HTML? if so, then you shouldn't put the "&lt" etc entities -> that makes the exact opposite from what you want - it keeps the "less than" character in the string.
So, if I understood you well, your code has to be

```
<div class="ratingText " id="rabidRating-9-description">2.8/5 <div class="rate"> (141 avis)</div></div>
```

Good luck.

Comment: the getStarmessage is displaying the text as "<div class="ratingText " id="rabidRating-9-description">2.8/5 &lt;div class="rate"&gt; (141 avis)&lt;/div&gt;</div>" and i am tring to convert the &lt entities to "less than" caracter, that is my objectif